# Bootstrap CSS misalignments

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have bootstrap downloaded and have the following piece of code.

```html
<header id="top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                    <image alt="here will be the logo" src=""></image>
                </div>
                <div  class="col-sm-6 ">

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" >
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="document">Document:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="document" placeholder="document">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="revision">Revision:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input class="form-control" id="revision" placeholder="revision">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pagenr">Page nr:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input class="form-control" readonly = "true" id="pagenr" placeholder="here will be page number">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="iso">ISO:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input class="form-control" id="iso" placeholder="iso">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

Here is the result i get : [web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZwMS.png) 
Now what interests me is 1. the alignment of text inside the forms (for some reason label is positioned higher than the input) and 2. the huge right margin which does not go away whatever i try to do and eats away input space. On a sidenote it's also interesting that making input field 'readonly' makes it perpetually gray.
Here is my css code:

```css
input.form-control{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 15px 22px;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 10px;
    border:0;
    background-color: #FFEBCD;
}
header {
    padding-top: 20px;  
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
div.container
{
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    border-right: 1px;
}
div.form-group
{
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    border-right: 1px;
}
form.form-horizontal
{
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    border-right: 1px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
div.row
{
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    border-right: 1px;
}
label.control-label
{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline ;
    background-color: CadetBlue;
    text-align: left;
}
```

So none of the vertical or text alignment attributes seem to work nor setting `'right margin' = 1px` to any element I can think of.
The Html code I provided only covers the first form, since the whole code would just be twice as big and the problem is obviously the same with second form.

Comment: You look like you're in big trouble. I'm editing their code. I'll make a comeback with code.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited their code. I hope it's the way you wanted it to be. It's really complicated wrote.

```
  <header id="top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
          <image alt="here will be the logo" src=""></image>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="col-sm-6 ">

        </div> -->
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2" for="document">Document:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control " id="document" placeholder="document">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="revision">Revision:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="revision" placeholder="revision">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pagenr">age nr:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="pagenr" placeholder="here will be page number">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="iso">ISO:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="iso" placeholder="iso">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: that fixed neither of the problems. And from what i can tell you made a 4-8 split instead of  3-6-3 which made input forms longer, but did not adress the issue of right margin which is still the same size nor the text missalignment within the form. Perhaps you misunderstood me

Answer (score 0):

Ok,so i did fix the text misallignment by juggling line-height of both form elements until they looked good enought. When you colour the boxes you still see the misalignment though. And right margin was so big because the left was too small if that makes sense